# Django with Huey task consumer: TestCase methods touch real DB

Tags: django, python-huey

I'm writing a Django application employing the Huey task queue, configured as described in [the relevant Huey docs](https://huey.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contrib.html#django). Running some basic tests, I disabled the `immediate` setting to try the `manage.py run_huey` command to run the task consumer in its own process.

I then ran a Django `TestCase` that invokes a Huey task that writes to the database (which, inside a `TestCase`, should be a temporary database created for and destroyed after testing.) The task was consumed in the Huey process and functioned as expected; however, the object created in the task run by the test was written to my actual (development) database.

I understand why -- whatever magic Django does to spin up a fake database when running tests just doesn't reach across to the Huey consumer process; and I understand that per the Huey docs, its default behavior is to run in immediate mode (executing tasks as soon as they are enqueued without running a scheduling database or a separate consumer process) when Django's `DEBUG` setting is enabled, so I was stepping out on a limb.

However, I feel like I some of the standard Huey features that aren't available in immediate mode -- scheduling tasks to occur in the future, running weightier computations in separate threads or processes -- are things I would want to test or experiment with in development. **Hence, my question: is there a good way to configure Huey with Django to accomplish this -- for TestCase's database mocking to work as intended when Huey tasks are consumed in a separate process?**

(I am very new to Django, testing, pretty much all of this so I'm happy to listen to arguments that this is outside the scope of behavior I should be concerned with testing.)

Comment: You shouldn't need to trigger the tasks in your tests, it should be enough just to call them and test their output in the test process. If you want to have tests for your applications talking to each other I would suggest having some integration test environment where these can be run